# I'm trying list comprehensions for printing 0's and 1's but it gives an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

So basically I'm trying to print an 8x8 grid witch has 0's and 1's like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I need it in a nested loop.
And I'm using this code but it Isn't working:

```
def print_board(board):
    board = [1 for i in range(8)] + board[3:]
    board = board[::-1] #reverse
    board = [1 for i in range(8)] + board[3:]
    for i in range(len(board)):
        print(board[i])
        print(" ".join([str(x) for x in board[i]]))
board=[]
for i in range(8):
        board.append([0] * 8)
print_board(board)
```

the error is:

```
001 | 1
002 | Traceback (most recent call last):
003 |   File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
004 |   File "<string>", line 7, in print_board
005 | TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Using latest version (3.10) of python

Comment: Always include error messages and/or failure symptoms.

Comment: Really not sure what you're after here. What are the inputs? Why must if be a nested loop?

Comment: Note: The reason to include the errors is that people like you can find similar problems and solutions online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is really what you're looking for but:

```
a = []

for i in range(8):
    match i:
        case 3 | 4:
            r = [0] * 8
        case _:
            r = [1] * 8
    a.append(r)

for r in a:
    print(*r)
```

**Output:**

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Seems without the input, you could also `[print(" ".join(["1" if r in [4, 5] else "0" for n in range(8)])) for r in range(8)]`.

Comment: You could do it like that but anyone reading it would spend most of their life trying to understand it. Also, I think the real objective is to produce at 2D list and not just to print out the table as shown in the OP's question. I may be wrong. I often am

Comment: No, I agree. That was 80% tongue in cheek. My point is that it is difficult to speculate without knowing how the inputs are coming. I'm sure you're right.